# Unique Meta Data for every article on joomla 3

Tags: meta-tags, joomla3.7

I can't add different meta data for articles.

There is my system configuration page:

[image: joomla 3 system configuration]

In article publishing page I set specific metadata for article:

[image: article publishing]

BUT in page source shows different metadata which is none of them.

[image: page source]

How can I solve this problem.

P.S. I've cleared the cache and restarted the server, it didn't work!

Comment: Please ask all Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use components like https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/site-management/seo-a-metadata/eorisis-metadata/

Metadata is a very powerful, advanced, modern and user friendly SEO Component, that allows you to organize, edit and maintain any kind of metadata on your site. You can freely create custom meta elements and attributes, organize them into nested categories, order them in your own way and use them on any page. Metadata component is written with MVC Architecture, with full ACL and permissions system, a plethora of options, is "extension independent" and can be used site-wide.